# Luigi Pipeline in Dockerfile; unknown instruction PYTHONPATH

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, luigi

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [
'PYTHONPATH="."', 'luigi', '--module', 'pipe',
'CreateAndFillIndex',
'--index', 'test',
'--http-auth', 'username:password',
'--host', 'localhost',
'--port', '9200'
 ]
```

Executing `docker build -t suggestpipe . && docker run -it suggestpipe`
 with this Dockerfile I get the error:

`unknown instruction: "PYTHONPATH='.'",`

and if I remove that instruction, I get `unknown instruction: "LUIGI",` so what am I doing wrong?

In requirements.txt there is a luigi dependency. And 'PYTHONPATH='.' was needed for running locally outside of Docker on my Mac, so I moved that CMD instruction into the Dockerfile too, but I am not sure if I need it. How do I run my pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dockerfile syntax isn't actually JSON, and you can't have a line break after the `[`.  Docker in effect rewrites this to

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "["]
```

(which would actually be valid!  You probably have a `/bin/[` binary!  But the container would exit immediately with status code 0.)

and then moves on to the next line

```
"PYTHONPATH='.'", "luigi", "--module", "pipe",
```

where it gets confused because this doesn't actually look like a Dockerfile directive.

Just removing that newline on its own only gets you partway there.  If you run

```
CMD ["PYTHONPATH='.'", "luigi", ...]
```

Docker won't launch a shell to try to run this; instead, it will look for a binary named exactly `PYTHONPATH='.'` in the usual directories, and when it doesn't find *e.g.* `/usr/bin/PYTHONPATH='.'` it will complain.

You shouldn't need to set this environment variable at all (especially since the `pip install` step will install packages into the image's isolated global Python installation), and I'd just delete it:

```
CMD ["luigi", ...]
```

If you *do* need to set it, you need to use an explicit ENV directive

```
ENV PYTHONPATH .
```

Comment: (Not part of this answer, but the `--host localhost` option makes me twitchy; I'm guessing it will imply that the process will be unreachable outside the container, if it's setting the bind address, and you _always_ need to set it to 0.0.0.0 in Docker.)

Comment: Thanks; with ENV=... it works now. I still get the error that luigi is unknown, but that is because I forgot to start the luigi-daemon, I will research myself how to fix it. The localhost parameter is just a dummy, later an environment variable will go there and will reference an elasticsearch endpoint in a cloud. as for the luigi-daemon I will forward its port when the Dockerfile works in general

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that you are providing the CMD instruction. You are currently using the exec form, but you are relying on shell behavior. Details on this can be found in the [Dockerfile documentation on the CMD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

The fix is to convert it to shell format like so:

```
CMD PYTHONPATH='.' luigi --module pipe CreateAndFillIndex --index test --http-auth username:password --host localhost --port 9200
```

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable using the ENV instruction ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env))

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=.
CMD [ "luigi", "--module", "pipe", 'CreateAndFillIndex', '--index', 'test', '--http-auth', 'username:password', '--host', 'localhost', '--port', '9200' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: 
unknown instruction: "'PYTHONPATH='.'",

You have added unnecessary ticks (') before and after PYTHONPATH=, which is considered a command output capturing in the shell terms. Delete the unnecessary ticks and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, that was just bad copy-pasting. With `'PYTHONPATH="."', 'luigi', '--module', 'pipe',` I still get the same error